# How to calculate percentage saved for goods

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have a product which has retail price and asking price. The retail price is $999$ and d asking price is $500$. How can I calculated the percentage saved?

- retail price = $999$
- asking price = $500$
- percentage saved = %?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\text{percentage saved}=\frac{\text{amount saved}}{\text{original price}}\times 100\%$$

Comment: thanks. i will add dis to my app.

Comment: how do i get the amount saved

Comment: $amount saved = retail - asking$

Comment: @Uchenna: Well, how much would you have spent without the discount? How much did you end up spending?

Comment: @Foo: If you want the text to come out un-italicized, `$\text{stuff}$` gives you $\text{stuff}$.

Comment: i did that calculation and the percentage is still 0%. that's why i asked so i can be sure

Comment: Are you dividing ints, so$\frac {499}{999}=0?$

Comment: looks like its from my the way i am telling the program to calculate it

Comment: finally gotten it to work thanks @RossMillikan for your question

Comment: @Uchenna: In that case, you can get a better approximation from $$\frac{(\text{retail price}-\text{asking price})\times 100}{\text{retail price}}.$$

Comment: thanks @CameronBuie the approximation works perfectly fine